# Sandbox to protect websites that allow users to upload styles

Tags: javascript, security, sandbox

A lot of websites like Tumblr, Posterous allow users to upload their own styles. The personal styles may contain both HTML, Javascript and server code. So my questions are

1. How to prevent users from uploading malicious server code.
2. How to prevent users from uploading malicious client code (Javascript).

I fairly understand how to solve (1) by limiting the set of functions to be used. I'm more concerned in (2) because it's very hard to filter bad codes. The styles could contain malicious codes that send user sessions to some external sources and then fake their identities. I've noticed that uploaded styles are not in an external frames, so stealing user sessions seems to be an obvious concern.

Does anyone have better knowledge for above questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't allow users to upload server code.
2. Don't allow users to upload client code.

It is not possible to filter all evil code. Google is trying to do so in the Play Store and regularly proves that point.